# Adding up all pairs of columns of two matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, combinations, addition

I have two matrices A and B with an equal amount of columns but generally an unequal amount of rows. I want to add up all pairs of columns from matrix A and B. A naive implementation with a for-loop is this:

```
import numpy as np
ncol = 3
nrow_A = 5
nrow_B = 10
A = np.ones((nrow_A,ncol))
B = np.zeros((nrow_B,ncol))

C = np.empty((nrow_A*nrow_B,ncol))
k = 0
for i in range(nrow_A):
    for j in range(nrow_B):
        C[k,:] = A[i,:]+B[j,:] 
        k += 1
```

which in this example returns a 50*3 matrix filled with ones. It feels like this should be possible with a single line of code. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reshape `A` slightly, you can add the two matrices together and concatenate the entries in the  first axis of the resulting array:

```
>>> np.concatenate(A[:,np.newaxis,:] + B)
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       ...
```

A slightly quicker alternative to `concatenate` is to use `reshape`:

```
(A[:,np.newaxis,:] + B).reshape(-1, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks. Isn't concatenate quite an expensive operation though?

Comment: @Forzaa - that's true, it can be; you can use `reshape` instead (I've added it to the answer)

Comment: Great! Really handy use of numpy functions. At the moment I'm not experienced enough yet to see all the possibilities, so it's really good to see these examples.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty but this line uses broadcasting to do the same thing:

```
(A[:, np.newaxis, :] + B[np.newaxis, :, :]).reshape(nrow_A * nrow_B, ncol)
```

Example

```
import numpy as np
ncol = 3
nrow_A = 5
nrow_B = 10
A = np.random.random_sample((nrow_A,ncol))
B = np.random.random_sample((nrow_B,ncol))

C = np.empty((nrow_A*nrow_B,ncol))
k = 0
for i in range(nrow_A):
    for j in range(nrow_B):
        C[k,:] = A[i,:]+B[j,:] 
        k += 1

D = (A[:, np.newaxis, :] + B[np.newaxis, :, :]).reshape(nrow_A * nrow_B, ncol)

print(np.allclose(C, D))
```

Comment: Ty. You gave almost the same answer as Ajcr, but since his version also includes an alternative I accepted that one.